# Where is my /boot/grub/menu.lst file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I m using VMware for my linux version Ubuntu 11.04 and i have searched for /boot/grub/menu.lst file but this file was not there. Why??

I was creating a new kernel in virtual linux but unable to create because of proper configuration file.So how i will get the proper config file for ubuntu 11.04 for kernel version 2.6.34??

Comment: What boot loader are you using?

Comment: i m using grub boot loader

Comment: If that really is the case (I don't know Ubunut) then I suggest you list the layout of `/boot/grub`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 9.10, the default bootloader is now grub2 (package name `grub-pc`). It works differently than grub 1.

The main configuration file is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but it is autogenerated and you should not modify it directly. To generate it, run the `update-grub` command, which is just a wrapper for `grub-mkconfig`. What it does is read the configuration file `/etc/default/grub` and execute all scripts inside `/etc/grub.d`.

Comment: I have done this for new kernel but after that the new kernel was not responding,black screen appears after selecting that option.
Any reason or solution for this.

Comment: After compiling the new kernel, have you generated a new `initrd` image? Have you run `update-grub` after generating the `initrd`? If you have done these steps, it is probably that the error is in your kernel compilation, not in grub.

Comment: yes i have done all these steps after compiling..but it ws not returning out from black screen..

Comment: It then seems a problem with your kernel. Try to compile the kernel with the same settings you have in the default ubuntu kernel. You can find them at `/boot/config-KERNEL_VERSION`

Comment: I have compiled it with default settings but it was not working.I dont know what will be the problem.